# How to calculate multiples of values that sum to a given value?

Tags: python, combinations, mathematical-optimization

I've got an optimization problem where I am trying to find the optimum number of products that add up a specific $ value. All items must be selected and repetition is allowed. For example:

```
desired total >= 12 and <= 13
hat $3
shoes $5
tie $2
```

results could be:

```
1 hat, 1 shoes, 2 tie
2 hat, 1 shoes, 1 tie
```

This is a discovery problem at work and not homework. I found this solution in another thread but could not quite fix it to work.

```
import itertools
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 7, 7, 9, 10]
result = [seq for i in range(len(numbers), 0, -1) for seq in itertools.combinations(numbers, i) if sum(seq) == 10]
print result
```

It works with a bunch of random numbers but when I raise my min value from e.g. `10` to `25` and alter the input arrary to floating point numbers `0 < x <= 1.5` it doesn't work.

Any direction on how to get this working is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: support repetition and  `>=` specific value, it will be infinite possible solutions?

Comment: is a range a better constraint then since it's float, `>=25 and < 26`?

Comment: all items must be selected, right?

Comment: Yes. Think of a wish-list and a budget. How many of each item on my wish list can I fit in my budget?

Comment: so you use lower bound and upper bound here is only for float reason, actually you want to equal some value? or you want to find all the possible result in particular bound?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: uh...which one? first or second? it is very different in implementation @dweeb

Comment: I’d like it to be at least a specific value at which point the iteration can stop. I only care about a minimum value. I made it a range because with the floats it might not be exact.

Comment: I would formulate this as an integer programming problem and use `pulp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me clarify your requirement first:

1. all items must be selected at least once
2. find the all possible result sum up >= lower_bound and <= upper_bound
3. items can be used repetitively
4. find all the combinations instead of permutations (don't care about order)

you can use backtrack to get what you want:

```
def find_all(data, lower, upper):
    total = sum([d[1] for d in data])
    lower -= total
    upper -= total      # all items must be selected at least once
    if upper < lower or lower < 0:
        return []

    results = []
    def backtrack(end, lower, upper, path):
        if end < 0: return
        if lower <= 0 <= upper:  # satified the condition
            results.append(path)
            return

        if upper >= data[end][1]:
            new_path = path[:]
            new_path[end] += 1
            backtrack(end, lower - data[end][1], upper - data[end][1], new_path)    # choose the last one
        backtrack(end - 1, lower, upper, path)      # don't choose the last one

    backtrack(len(data) - 1, lower, upper, [1] * len(data))
    return results
```

test:

```
def print_results(results, data):
    for result in results:
        for count, d in zip(result, data):
            print(f'{count}*{d[0]}', end=', ')
        print()
    print()


data1 = [('hat', 3), ('shoes', 5), ('tie', 2)]
print_results(find_all(data1, 12, 13), data1)

data2 = [('hat', 3), ('shoes', 5), ('tie', 2), ('cloth', 10)]
print_results(find_all(data2, 25, 28), data2)
```

output

```
1*hat, 1*shoes, 2*tie, 
2*hat, 1*shoes, 1*tie, 

1*hat, 1*shoes, 4*tie, 1*cloth, 
2*hat, 1*shoes, 3*tie, 1*cloth, 
1*hat, 2*shoes, 2*tie, 1*cloth, 
2*hat, 1*shoes, 2*tie, 1*cloth, 
1*hat, 2*shoes, 1*tie, 1*cloth, 
3*hat, 1*shoes, 1*tie, 1*cloth,
```

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Comment: btw, notice this line, `if lower <= 0 <= upper:` break out once reach the lower bound, like you said "care about a minimum value.", so some more result will omit @dweeb